# HttpServletRequest attributes and parms getting "lost"? with 1.6 JavaEE spec?

Tags: java, servlets

Our code - which has not changed, is behaving differently in JavaEE1.4 than it did in 1.6 with respect to HttpServletRequest attributes and parameters. However this different behavior is not (always) consistent. We are also using BEA Weblogic 10 (vs. version 8, where it still works).

For example: 
In some cases when we do a "request.setAttribute(name, value)" and later on do a "request.getAttribute(name)" - there seems so be no such "name" at all in the request - as if we've never set it. I have run this through our Eclipse debugger in both 8v3 and Ja11 and I do see this attribute in 8v3 but cannot find it in Ja11, which is consistent with how the code is behaving.

Our code consistently fails in in at least one case, where the values of "name" and "value" are both defined as "public final static String;"

I have coded around this one particular instance line by getting the information I need via "request.getPathInfo" instead, however I SUSPECT the same or similar problem is occurring elsewhere in our code - but in one other such instance it is so entirely SPORADIC that I have been unable to recreate it while in debug mode (or even in putting Sysout statements) and therefore cannot trap the line that is the problem. In another instance, also one I can't definitively trap - I believe that it's the request.getParameter(name) that is not returning anything even though that "name" does exist on the jsp form, with data.

(Note that I am somewhat simplifying what our code actually looks like as we have an entire RequestContext class which mplementsSerializable and encapsulates all the relevant data and methods for one request cycle of an HttpServlet - ie HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, HttpSession, HttpServlet

Anyway I have heard that the Java Servlet spec has had some changes in 1.6 - but does it somewhere explicity state what those differences are or do I literally have to pull up the 1.4 spec next to it and do my own compare???

I am admittedly not well versed in dealing with HttpServeltRequest, but this code has been working FINE for YEARS - have a hard time believing something so basic/common as get/setAttribute and getParameter would have changed...

Comment: sorry - when I refer to "8v3" and "Ja11" I am referring to Weblogic 8 (and Java 1.4) for "8v3" and am referring to Weblogic 10 (and Java 1.6) for "Ja11"

Comment: sounds like a bug in the container

Answer (score 0):

Servlets are not thread-safe and do not get recreated per request. All requests are being served by one and the same servlet object. Are you storing variables in public static final fields of the servlet class?

Comment: I don't believe so. The public final static String variablel to which I referred is in a Delegate class